# neo4j query on number of matches in a set

Tags: neo4j

I have a relation like this:

```
context-[EXPRESSED_AS]->root
```

Assume that I have two contexts. The first has roots with base_forms of "temperature", "cool" and "hot". The second has roots with base_forms of "cool" and "hot". I want to find all contexts, sorted by the *number of matches* for the set ["cool", "temperature"].

I attempted it using this Cypher query, which gets close but doesn't quite work:

```
MATCH (n:Context)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:EXPRESSED_AS]->(r)
WHERE r.base_form IN ["cool","temperature"]
RETURN c, count(r) as c
ORDER BY c DESC
```

This returns contexts in the expected order, but the `c` values are the same. I expect `c` to equal the number of matches in the set, which should be 2 and 1 respectively.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: i need to have more info, does one context can be associated with multiple "temperature" roots ?

Comment: Yes, roots may have more than one context.

Comment: I asked for the inverse :) So your first context will have 3 relationships : 1 to root 'cool', 1 to root 'temperature' and 1 to root 'hot', or can have 3 relationshops to root 'cool' for e.g. N

Comment: can you come to the chatroom ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67863/context-and-roots

Comment: Each context->root relation is unique, but roots have many contexts. I'm basically trying to find the best match for a context based on the number of matching roots.

Comment: By looking at your graph http://console.neo4j.org/?id=kz1npw there is no chance that a match for "cool" and "temperature" can occur more than once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query match for e.g. all contexts and optinally match contexts that contain two specific roots :

```
MATCH (n:Context)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)<-[:EXPRESSED_AS]-(r)
WHERE r.base_form = "cool" AND r.base_form = "hot"
WITH count(r) AS c, n
ORDER BY c DESC 
RETURN n, c
```

Neo4j console link : http://console.neo4j.org/r/9sexaf

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion. I want results like this given the data I provided before: context 1 should indictate 2 roots matching the set, context 2 should show 1 root matching the set. The number of matches is the data I need to find, because I'm looking for a 'best fit' result.

Comment: Well according to the graph you provided and the query I ran on it in the shared console here : http://console.neo4j.org/r/9sexaf, it seems like it is returning what you want ?

Comment: I was running the query locally and my data was mismatched. Your query ran beautifully.